# How to distribute .NET Core Console App with brew

Tags: .net-core, homebrew

May I ask for some guidance on how I can package and distribute a .NET Core Console App so that its available via `brew` for Mac. To be specific, I have this small tool that already works with `dotnet tool install` on Ubuntu and Windows and I wish to also wish make the tool available in Mac without .NET Core SDK.

Current setup and already working in Windows:

```sh
dotnet tool install -g yuniql.cli
choco install yuniql
```

Current setup and already working in Ubuntu:

```sh
dotnet tool install -g yuniql.cli
```

Desired setup in MacOS:

```
brew install yuniql
```

TIA.

Comment: How would you describe the installation of this tool "by hand", without using `dotnet tool install`?

Comment: Hi @bfontaine, if i get your commrnt right... i want to install the tool using package manager in MacOs such as Homebrew. I had some guidance in linux for APT and I used Chocolatey on windows. For MacOS, I so far can't find a guide for dotnetcore apps.

Comment: I don’t know how dotnetcore apps are built and I can’t find one in Homebrew’s repo, so I’d like to know which commands should the Homebrew package run in order to build and install your package. Maybe you can point me an open-source basic app that’s similar to yours.

Comment: Hi @bfontaine, trying to do the same. Did you manage to do that eventually? what did you end up doing?

Comment: @OhadBitton No, I was just trying to help the OP but he didn’t respond to my questions so I couldn’t try anything. I’m familiar with writing Homebrew packages but I never worked with .NET apps.